# Install of Multichain

Tags: software-installation

Hi I am new to Ubuntu and am trying to install multichain to Ubuntu 12 on DigitalOcean. When I follow all the steps for the install i get a "cannot execute binary file"... can anyone help this newbie figure out what he is doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Log into your DigitalOcean (virtaul) machine and follow the installation instructions according to [MultiChain](http://www.multichain.com/download-install/) website:

> su (enter root password) 
>   cd /tmp 
>   wget http://www.multichain.com/download/multichain-1.0-alpha-19.tar.gz 
>   tar -xvzf multichain-1.0-alpha-19.tar.gz 
>   cd multichain-1.0-alpha-19
>   mv multichaind multichain-cli multichain-util /usr/local/bin 
>   exit

Now that the installation is complete with binary in `/usr/local/bin/`, you can follow the [detailed instructions](http://www.multichain.com/getting-started/) on getting started.

Comment: when i follow the above and log back in i get mv: target user/local/bin is not a directory

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/`, not `user/local/bin`